# Why is this simple MemoryStream.Write() experiment failing?

Tags: .net, memorystream

I am flummoxed by a basic experiment using a writable `System.IO.MemoryStream` based on a byte array giving an ArgumentException

1. The array `newBytes` is initialised with a literal
2. The memory stream `ms` is initialised with the array and the writable flag set to `True`
3. The memory stream is written with one byte at position 1

---

VB.net

```
Try
    Dim newBytes() As Byte = {0, 128, 255, 128, 0}
    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(newBytes, True)
    ms.Write({CByte(4)}, 1, 1)
Catch ex as Exception
End Try
```

C#.net

```
try
    byte() newBytes = {0, 128, 255, 128, 0};
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(newBytes, true);
    ms.Write(byte(4), 1, 1);
catch Exception ex
end try
```

The Exception is an `ArgumentException` with text "Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection."

Evidently the memory stream has `Length: 5` and writing one byte at position 1 should be perfectly doable, why is there an exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MemoryStream.Write` method has three parameters:

- `buffer` - The buffer to write data from
- `offset` - The zero-based byte offset in buffer at which to begin copying bytes to the current stream
- `count` - The maximum number of bytes to write

Note that the second parameter is the offset in the input array, not the offset in the output array.  The `MemoryStream.Position` property determines the current offset in the output.

Comment: Exactaly, and if you want to determine the position to start writing, you'll need to use MemoryStream Seek method.

Comment: @OberdanNunes The Position property is writable, so `ms.Position = 0` works too.

Comment: This is the correct answer, an annoyingly subtle flaw in my understanding of the MSDN page..! I will now start asking about changing the SoundPlayer.Stream.Write() method, but before I do, is there anything you may know that will save me the question? Basically I would like to write to the sound buffer while it is playing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `SoundPlayer` class, specifically, so, probably not.